# Round UIImage disappear

Tags: swift

I set my image works well like this:

```
self.avatarImageView.image                  = self.avatarImage
```

But, when i want to change it to circle in this way the image disappear.

```
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds    = true
self.avatarImageView.image                  = self.avatarImage
self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius     = self.avatarImageView.frame.width/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to layout it works.

```
 self.avatarImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
```